# Can't find or load main class error in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

[Here](http://alans.se/blog/2010/hadoop-hbase-cygwin-windows-7-x64/) is the tutorial that am following. I got error when i am trying to execute the command `bin/hadoop namenode -format`.

The error is:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName DEPRECATED: Use of this script to
>   execute hdfs command is deprecated. Instead use the hdfs command for
>   it.
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName Error: Could not find or load main
>   class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode

any help ?

Comment: to be honest, with the given information i cant say about the problem here. Maybe you should follow some other tutorial. I had used this one lot of time: http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~cs147a/lab/hadoop-windows/ and it worked good for me.

Comment: also, if you are following a particular tutorial, take care that u are using the exact same version mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my 2 cents. I had the same issue, I re-installed hadoop in a unix environment and it worked fine. Cygwin has some weird issues with hadoop plus windows is not a good platform for hadoop.

Answer (score -1):

hdfs namenode -format

Error: Could not find or load main class xyz

you are getting this error maybe because your username contains white space 
or blank space like amit kumar, pavan singh etc.

to solve this problem:

Go to your C:\hadoop-2.7.7\etc\hadoop

and open the file hadoop-env.cmd in any text editor and at the end replace 
%USERNAME%
with any name but without space

REPLACE THIS
**set HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=%USERNAME%**

WITH THIS

**set HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=AMIT**

OR simply follow this video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6wck9dKVKQ

Comment: Hi Amit, it would be useful to post the code sample rather than an image as external links have a tendancy not to age well.