# Not been able to configure hadoop-1.2.1 on windows

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, command, cygwin

I could able to configure hadoop-0.19.1 on my windows system and followed steps given in

http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/09%20-%20unpack%20hadoop.html

Now I am trying to configure hadoop-1.2.1 following the same steps but I am stucked at command

> $ bin/hadoop namenode -format

and it is giving me the error as shown below

```
313159@PC213710 ~
$ cd hadoop-1.2.1

313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-1.2.1
$ bin/hadoop namenode -format
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 15: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 19: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 21: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 26: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 30: cd: /home/31
: No such file or directory
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 32: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 35: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: syntax error
: unexpected end of file
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.
NameNode

313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-1.2.1
$ ssh-host-config

*** ERROR: There are still ssh processes running. Please shut them down first.

313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-1.2.1
$ ssh-host-config

*** Query: Overwrite existing /etc/ssh_config file? (yes/no) yes
*** Info: Creating default /etc/ssh_config file
*** Query: Overwrite existing /etc/sshd_config file? (yes/no) yes
*** Info: Creating default /etc/sshd_config file
*** Info: Privilege separation is set to yes by default since OpenSSH 3.3.
*** Info: However, this requires a non-privileged account called 'sshd'.
*** Info: For more info on privilege separation read /usr/share/doc/openssh/READ
ME.privsep.
*** Query: Should privilege separation be used? (yes/no) yes
*** Info: Updating /etc/sshd_config file
*** Query: Overwrite existing /etc/inetd.d/sshd-inetd file? (yes/no) yes
*** Info: Creating default /etc/inetd.d/sshd-inetd file
*** Info: Updated /etc/inetd.d/sshd-inetd

*** Info: Sshd service is already installed.

*** Info: Host configuration finished. Have fun!

313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-1.2.1
$ cd ..

313159@PC213710 ~
$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/313159/.ssh/id_rsa):
/home/313159/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/313159/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/313159/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
21:45:11:30:6b:3a:af:c6:4a:2d:ed:3a:bf:be:69:be 313159@PC213710
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|      oo=o       |
|       +         |
|      + .        |
|     o . .       |
|    o   S        |
|   o o           |
|  o.o .          |
| ..o+o           |
|  oXE+           |
+-----------------+

313159@PC213710 ~/.ssh
$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 313159 mkpasswd 2004 Feb 18 11:59 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 313159 mkpasswd  668 Oct 21 12:06 id_dsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 313159 mkpasswd  605 Oct 21 12:06 id_dsa.pub
-rw------- 1 313159 mkpasswd 1679 Feb 18 11:57 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 313159 mkpasswd  397 Feb 18 11:57 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 313159 mkpasswd  171 Oct 21 12:00 known_hosts

313159@PC213710 ~/.ssh
$ cd ..

313159@PC213710 ~
$ cd hadoop-1.2.1

313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-1.2.1
$ bin/hadoop namenode -format
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 15: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 19: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 21: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 26: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 30: cd: /home/31
: No such file or directory
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 32: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 35: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: syntax error
: unexpected end of file
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.
NameNode

313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-1.2.1
$ cd bin

313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-1.2.1/bin
$ dos2unix *.sh
dos2unix: converting file hadoop-config.sh to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file hadoop-daemon.sh to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file hadoop-daemons.sh to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file slaves.sh to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file start-all.sh to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file start-balancer.sh to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file start-dfs.sh to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file start-jobhistoryserver.sh to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file start-mapred.sh to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file stop-all.sh to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file stop-balancer.sh to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file stop-dfs.sh to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file stop-jobhistoryserver.sh to Unix format ...
dos2unix: converting file stop-mapred.sh to Unix format ...

313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-1.2.1/bin
$ cd ..

313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-1.2.1
$ cd conf

313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-1.2.1/conf
$ dos2unix *.sh
dos2unix: converting file hadoop-env.sh to Unix format ...

313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-1.2.1/conf
$ cd ..

313159@PC213710 ~/hadoop-1.2.1
$ bin/hadoop namenode -format
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 15: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 19: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 21: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 26: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 30: cd: /home/31
: No such file or directory
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 32: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 35: $'\r': comma
nd not found
/home/313159/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 87: syntax error
: unexpected end of file
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.
NameNode
```

Can anyone please suggest/share me solution for the problem
Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839705/cant-find-or-load-main-class-error-in-hadoop and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852199/hdfs-namenood-formatting-error-could-not-find-the-main-class-namenood-code-a

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably the newline character difference in Unix and in Windows.

I think that the answer is to run the `dos2unix` command for this file, as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616835/cygwin-r-command-not-found-bashrc-bash-profile) [possible duplicate].